# How can I use if statement in render function?

Tags: reactjs

Below is my render method.
I want to loop through `toptracks` only if it is not `null`. 
But I am not able to get this working.

```
render() {
   console.log('galler props',this.props);

    const { toptracks } = this.props;
    return (
       <div>
        if(this.props.toptracks !== null){

        {toptracks.map((toptracks,k) => {
          const trackImg =toptracks.track[0].image[0]['#text'];
          return (
              <div
                  key = {k}
                  className ="track"
                  >
                  <img
                     src={trackImg}
                     className="trackImg"
                     alt="track"
                     />
                     <p className="tracl-text">
                               {track.name}
                         </p>
                         </div>      

                             )
                         }
                       ) 
                     }
         }

         </div>
    ) 
}
```

Comment: Please describe what error you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an if statement within your render-return statement. You can make use of ternary statement like

```
render() {
        const { toptracks } = this.props;
        return (
           <div>

            {this.props.toptracks ? toptracks.map((toptracks,k) => {
              const trackImg =toptracks.track[0].image[0]['#text'];
              return (
                  <div key = {k} className ="track">
                      <img
                         src={trackImg}
                         className="trackImg"
                         alt="track"
                      />
                       <p className="tracl-text">
                           {track.name}
                       </p>
                   </div>      
                )
              }) : null}
             </div>
        ) 
    }
```

Comment: Bro it's showing this ERROR:Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @AaronKahn that your `toptracks` is `undefined` and not `null`. You can check using `!this.props.topTracks` instead. Or, instead of checking, give it a default value: `(this.props.topTracks || []).map(...)`, or use `defaultProps` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `if` is rather simple if you decide for an early return:

```
render() {
   const { toptracks } = this.props;

   if (!toptracks) { // this will handle both null and undefined
      return <div/>;
   }

   return (
      ...
   );
}
```

However, there are simpler ways to do that. Note that in your case having no value is the same as having an empty value. Why not default to an empty value instead then?

```
render() {
   const toptracks = this.props.toptracks || [];

   // no change needed here
}
```

The same can be done by defining `defaultProps` for your component.

```
static defaultProps = {
   toptracks: []
};
```

Comment: bro  atmost error are fix but  "toptracks.map" is not a function error is still there , how to fix it?

Comment: @AaronKahn Is it possible that `toptracks` is not even an array? If you are sending invalid data to your component, there's not much we can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `if` if you make that a functional component and add if statement inside that.

```
ShowTopTracks = () =>{
    if(this.props.toptracks){
        return toptracks.map((toptracks,k) => {
            const trackImg =toptracks.track[0].image[0]['#text'];
            return (
              <div
                  key = {k}
                  className ="track"
                  >
                  <img
                     src={trackImg}
                     className="trackImg"
                     alt="track"
                     />
                  <p className="tracl-text">
                     {track.name}
                  </p>
              </div>      
            )
        }) 
    }
    else return null;
}


render() {
   console.log('galler props',this.props);

    const { toptracks } = this.props;
    return (
       <div>
       {this.ShowTopTracks()}
       </div>
    ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, toptracks by itself is undefined, declare it at the start of the render function as

`const { toptracks } = this.props;`

then you can use it without referencing `this.props.toptracks`

Secondly the `map` function takes arguments of the element and the index but you have declared them as toptracks again which creates aliasing issues (at least in my mind) and is also just plain confusing...

`return toptracks.map((toptracks,k) =>`

should ideally be

`return toptracks.map((toptrack,k) =>` - then remember to update the toptracks inside the map callback to toptrack to make it clearer which is the collection and which is the element

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map for more info on the map function.

As already pointed out, if toptracks is not an array then you will need to turn it into an array or use .keys for example if it is an object.